# Removing a value from a custom linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
int SDI::LinkedList::removeValue(int removeValue)
{
SDI::Node* current = head;
SDI::Node* prev = head; 
    while (current != nullptr)
    {
        if (current == head)
        {
            if (current->value == removeValue)
            {
                current = current->next; // track the next value
                delete head;
                head = current-> next;
                return 1;
            }       

        }
        else
        {
            if (current->value != removeValue)
            {
                prev = current;  /// don’t lose track of the previous value, saves working 1 ahead
                current  = current-> next; // let the loop deal with it

            }
        else
        {
            prev->next = current->next;
            delete current;
        }
            if (current->next != nullptr)
            {
                if (current->next->value == removeValue)
                {
                SDI::Node* temp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                delete temp;
                return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

All seems to work well, until it reaches the line:

```
"if (current->value != removeValue)"
```

It seems to just jump directly over it, yet current-> value DOES NOT equal removeValue as shown in the watcher.

Comment: Are you compiling in Release mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have an infinite loop if `current->value != removeValue` on the first iteration of the loop as you'll never leave the `if (current == head)` condition since current will never update. If you change your first condition from `if (current == head)` to `if (current == head && current->value == removeValue)` it should now correctly reach the `current->value != removeValue` condition that you said was being skipped.

I don't see any additional errors beyond that without more details on the steps your program seems to be skipping.